# How to solve notorious 'Error Establishing a Database Connection'

Tags: database, fatal-error

I am facing 'error establishing a database connection', while I am trying to visit my site in browser. I am working in WordPress that is installed in my local computer. I have already done following things to troubleshoot:

*1. Checked the correctness of my DB_Name, DB_User, DB_Password and    DB_Host. (To do this I have used a php script to connect to database.    By that script I could successfully connect to database. So my    credentials are surely Okay.)

2. Also tried to put DB_Host as '120.0.0.1:3306' and 'localhost:3306'

3. I have also changed the MySQL Port(3306) to other values (as for       example to 3307).*

None of above steps was successful to solve my problem. 
This error is very notorious error of WordPress platform. Can any body have any solution.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are using to run your local enviroment e.g. MAMP?

Answer (score 1):

did you change or modify any core WordPress files? just make sure that core files are not modified. and i suggest you to double check the `wp-config.php` file for DB Configurations.

restart your local server (apache & php).

Try with following configuration.

```
DB HOST: '127.0.0.1'
DB USER: 'root'
DB PASS: '' (blank)
```

Comment: Hello Rehman, I tried your suggested solutions. But those were not effective for my case. But helped to work out solution. Thanks for your suggestion.
I solved my problem by following way:

Opened the phpMyAdmin> selected the appropriate the WordPress Database> made sure the structure tab is selected > selected all the tables> clicked the drop-down box (of which caption is 'with selected:') > selected the option 'Repaid table'.